# Garbled greeter/login screen

Tags: login, lightdm, login-screen

I have recently (as in beginning of 2017 recently) started having issues with garbled greeter/login screen. Once it happens, it does not fix itself even if I switch to console and back. When I type my password correctly, I get to see my session working normally. This is with Radeon and the free drivers on Yakkety (16.10).

Please advise.

[image]